# Google suspended my app for ads in background

Tags: android, admob

yesterday google suspended my app from google store saying that my ads were against google TOS. Basically there is a sort of bug, my fault obviously and in some devices the advertises keep showing also if you press home button and let the app in background.
I really don't know how to fix it.

This is xml code

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="INTERSTITIAL"
        ads:adUnitId="MyID" >
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

this is the main

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity 
{
    private WebView webView;
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;
    String Url="Myurl";
    List<String> segments = new ArrayList<String>();
    int delay = 120000; //milliseconds

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() 
          {
              //advertise();
              handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
          }
        }, 7000);
        //
    }



    public void advertise()
    {
                // Prepare the Interstitial Ad
                interstitial = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
                // Insert the Ad Unit ID
                interstitial.setAdUnitId("MyID");

                //Locate the Banner Ad in activity_main.xml
                AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);

                // Request for Ads
                AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()

                // Add a test device to show Test Ads
                 .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                 .addTestDevice("CC5F2C72DF2B356BBF0DA198")
                        .build();

                // Load ads into Banner Ads
                adView.loadAd(adRequest);

                // Load ads into Interstitial Ads
                interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

                // Prepare an Interstitial Ad Listener
                interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() 
                {
                    public void onAdLoaded() {
                        // Call displayInterstitial() function
                        displayInterstitial();
                    }
                });
    }
            public void displayInterstitial() 
            {
                // If Ads are loaded, show Interstitial else show nothing.
                if (interstitial.isLoaded()) 
                {
                    interstitial.show();
                }
            }*/

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
            {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
            }
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) 
                {
                    case R.id.twitter:          
                    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/salvoaranzulla"));
                    startActivity(browserIntent);
                    break;
                    case R.id.facebook:
                    Intent browserIntent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/salvoaranzulla?ref=ts&fref=ts"));
                    startActivity(browserIntent1);
                    break;
                 }
                return true;
            }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make your handler and runnable field variables and start and stop them like so.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, delay);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i ll try on monday. Sure it will work, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

If this problem is not happening in every phone it could possibly the problem is in that user's mobile settings.
 Just check whether in his/her " settings > Developer Options > Do not keep activities " selected or not.
 If it is selected then the app will destroy every activities as soon as the user left the current activity.
 So when an interstitial is displayed , the current activity will be normally in onPause.
 but it will be destroyed and when the user close the interstitial and come back again oncreate will
 run and the ad will display.

If you want to control this things when the activity is leaving focus, it belongs in onPause(), onStop() or onDestroy() depending on the level of control you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your app was probably banned because of this:

```
            // Prepare an Interstitial Ad Listener
            interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() 
            {
                public void onAdLoaded() {
                    // Call displayInterstitial() function
                    displayInterstitial();
                }
            });
```

Do **NOT** display an ad from `onAdLoaded()`, display it at a natural break point in your app.